# Is there any NoSQL DB implementation that has none separate daemon?

Tags: nosql

I do look for a simple NoSQL DB that such as Sqlite DB, i.e. that does not need to install a separate daemon. All files needed should be in my PHP application tree.
Do all NoSQL DB implementations need a separate daemon to be usable?

Answer (score 1):

[Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html)

The webpage above is very marketing oriented. Take a look also at the [Wikipedia page](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Berkeley_DB)

Comment: So interesting!!! but so Oracle. I mean, no real PHP API or binding, only for Java or C++; PHP mentioned but how to find a true native PHP API for Berkeley DB? Could you tell me?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you much with php. I've used Bdb only from python, and it was some years ago before Oracle acquired it. 
Googling around I've found some posts on using it with php, but it seems you have to do some configuration and installation on the server http://sepp.oetiker.ch/subversion-1.4.6-rp/ref/ext/php.html

Comment: Forgot to mention... Check the license. If nothing has changed it should be dual licensed under a free software license called Sleepycat License (by the name of company which mantained and sold the software) or commercial.

Answer (score 1):

[GT.M](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fis-gtm/) is another solution you should have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

ZODB? it is OO DB and follows NoSQL (Not Only SQL)

Comment: This is only for Python, so not a good solution as my projects do use other programming languages.

Comment: When I've written this, no language was specified. In any case you can use C-bindings to use between them.

Answer (score 0):

[There is solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822021/php-friendly-nosql-solutions) for your task!

Comment: PHPillow! But look/read: "PHPillow Prerequisites: #1 -> A running CouchDB installation from current trunk." I cannot install anything on my server so I do look for a solution that does not require me to install anything on the server. So this is not a solution.

Comment: also you can look here: http://nosql-database.org/ there many embedded databases engines

Comment: il_guru, in most cases you're right, but does this rule is applicable for stackoverflow or wikipedia-like links which can be found on first page in google search?